# Use class object as parameter in function to add to array

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to do a simple base where I can add memebers to array. I change a "Tour of Heroes" from Angular tutorial ([link](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/eplnkr.html)). What I want to do is instead of passing name (string) to function I would like to give a whole class object (User). I use form where user is typing his name and surname (and city if he want). I have no idea how to get from input to function this whole object, instead of list of string parameters. Here is my code:
**form.html**:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" required name="nameField" [(ngModel)]="ngModel"  #nameField="ngModel" > 
    <div [hidden]="nameField.valid || nameField.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Name is required</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surname">surname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" required name="surnameField" ngModel #surnameField="ngModel"> 
    <div [hidden]="surnameField.valid || surnameField.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Surname is required</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" ngModel #cityField="ngModel" > 
  </div> 

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!userForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**function on submit**:

```
onSubmit(name: string, surname: string, city: string ): void{
name = name.trim();
surname = surname.trim();
city = city.trim();

this.myservice.create(name, surname, city)
  .then(newUser => this.arrayUsers.push(newUser));
}
```

And **function create inside myservice**:

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private heroesUrl = 'api/mainArray';  // URL to web api
create(name: string, surname: string, city?: string): Promise<User> {
return this.http
  .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name, surname:surname, city:city}), {headers: this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().data as User);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `ngModel`  attribute to bind each input to the form :

For example :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel required name="nameField" > 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" ngModel required name="surnameField" > 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" ngModel required name="cityField" ngModel >
```

And in the `form` element, give a name to the form to be able to bind it in the component and add the form as parameter in the `onSubmit()` method :

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" >
```

Now you should be able to retrieve the user with the `f.value` property :

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm): void{

this.myservice.create(f.value)
  .then(createdUser=> this.arrayUsers.push(createdUser));
}
```

More information here : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: Thank You for answer. Could You tell me one more thing - What should I put inside declarations of parameters of" create" function inside my service?

Comment: I thought about create(array:string[]) but it ives me nothing to main array. And i put then JSON.stringify(array)

Comment: You are welcome. As disclaimer, I know AngularJS but not at all Angular (2). I suppose that If you want to pass to the create() method a User, the method should have as parameter a User.